# Is there any journal in which I can publish educational articles not a research article?

Tags: journals, teaching, physics

I want to publish an educational article about some non-standard approach to Lagrangian Mechanics, but the problem is that I have written it in my country language (not in English) so I want to know if there is any journal which accepts academical papers, I shall surely convert it into English if there exist one. I want to mention that I have no background in research, I'm a lecturer at one of the state Universities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One example would be the [American Journal of Physics](https://aapt.scitation.org/ajp/info/about) published by the American Association of Physics Teachers. Quoting from their Audience and Mission statement (at the link above):

> The mission of the American Journal of Physics (AJP) is to publish articles on the educational and cultural aspects of physics that are useful, interesting, and accessible to a diverse audience of physics students, educators, and researchers. Our audience generally reads outside their specialties to broaden their understanding of physics and to expand and enhance their pedagogical toolkits at the undergraduate and graduate levels.

They have quite a broad range of articles, many of which are of broad interest.

Answer (score 1):

The *International Journal of Mathematical Education in Science and Technology* (published by Taylor & Francis) has articles called *[Classroom Notes](https://think.taylorandfrancis.com/tmes-classroom-notes/)* which

> provide a space for short articles highlighting a single, unusual and interesting result, an alternative method, or a creative approach to teaching a particular mathematical idea. These  articles are intended to provoke ideas that will support our teaching of mathematics at school or university level

Answer (score 1):

The SIAM Review (published by the Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics) has articles called *[Education](https://www.siam.org/publications/journals/siam-review-sirev)* which

> consists primarily of individual modules that are self-contained presentations of specific topics in applied mathematics, scientific computation, or their applications; each module provides the primary material needed to teach a given topic as well as supplementary material.

Answer (score -3):

Yes: Some journals publish tutorials. Just add "tutorial" to your search terms and you should find something appropriate.